# Who can be clients in JMS

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I have list of emails (to many). I want to write scheduler, which sends emails periodically.

1. I read emails from database
2. I send messages to this emails.

As I see for good performance, it is good to use JMS (Topic) to make this.

In documentation I read that Topic sends messages to all clients. Could you enplane me what does "client" means at this case? In my opinion, wich my example,  they are the owner of the emails and my system will send the message text to this owner of email (Clients). Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in this context, "all clients" means all java processes that have an open subscription to the topic.

You would need to write code to convert from JMS to Email (and send it). Frameworks like [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) can be used for this, it does all the heavy lifting for you; you would simply wire a JMS message-driven-channel-adapter to receive the message from a queue (not a topic), do a JDBC query to get the emails, then send them via a mail outbound-channel-adapter.

Read the project documentation for more information (there's a link to it from the project page link above).

Comment: Thank you for your answer in the first instance! You tell me that I should have one open subscription client, which listens JMS (receives messages from JMS). then I should send it via outbound-channel-adapter. As I here JMS is for just pool. do I need it at all? I can send emails only with via a mail outbound-channel-adapter, is not it? Is there any benefit if I use JMS here?

Comment: No; you don't need JMS; you can just send messages directly to the mail adapter.

Comment: Ok. And could you give me en reall example, when can I use JMS. when it is erally usable. When should I use, which type of tasks does it solve.
Thanks in advance!